# MongoDB+Java - Find using current date

Tags: mongodb, date, isodate

I have MongoDB collection storing a "creation" time i.e. date field that holds the instant when the document was created. I would like to allow editing this document only if it is no more than, say, 3 days old. Also, I would like to not depend on the requester machine's time. So, following is not an option -

```
db.documents.find({
  "creation_time": {
    "$gt": DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofSecond(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)))
  }
})
```

Above code is computing the time based on client's machine. Instead I would like to base the computation on the database machine's time.

After some search, I came up with the following query -

```
db.documents.find({
  "creation_time": {
    "$gt": new Date(new ISODate() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  }
})
```

However, the above code requires passing js code as part of the query. I can't seem to find a way to pass this snippet using the java driver.

Any ideas/alternatives?

No this is absolutely not a duplicate, at least not a duplicate of the referenced question. Specific use case - I have a tool that talks directly to the backed database i.e. without a mediating server. I have a requirement that documents should be allowed to be modified for no more than 3 days from its creation date. This tool is to be used by many clients and if I use client's machine time, I will get inconsistent results, for obvious reasons. On top of that, there's a concern about clients finding workarounds like tuning their system clock back to circumvent the restriction.

After some more research and reading the Mongo docs, here's the solution. Hopefully, it helps some other soul some day.

```
db.documents.find({
  "created_at": {
    "_id": ObjectId("59cf75907bdf8d2e0c1c6f9a"),
    "$gt": new Date(new ISODate() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  }
})
```

In Java,

```
Bson filter = new BsonDocument()
        .append("_id", new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId("59cf75907bdf8d2e0c1c6f9a")))
        .append("$where", new BsonJavaScript("this.created_at > (new Date() - 259200000)"));
Bson update = new BsonDocument()
        .append("$set", new BsonDocument()
                .append("edited_by", new BsonString("abc@xyz.com")));
database.getCollection("documents").findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, (result, error) -> {
    if (error != null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to find any editable document);
    } else if (result != null) {
        System.out.println(result.getObjectId("_id").toHexString());
    }
});
```

The above code snippet computes the current time on the server machine and compares it with the document's field (created_at).

Here's the link to specific function used in the above snippet -
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html

Caution: There are some serious restrictions about the feature. Make sure you understand the restrictions and are acceptable for your use case.

Lesson learned!!

Comment: Anything returning `java.util.Date` is valid to pass in as an argument to the JavaDriver. JavaScript is for JavaScript and Python is for Python. Don't try and make Java do JavaScript or vice versa. Native/Defacto date format is you really need to think of.

Comment: The referenced duplicate is not the same. The dates are being computed on the client machine, not the database machine. I am looking for a way to base the math on the database machine's time.

Comment: You cannot "compute on the database". So learn the lesson.